# Ошибку: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть строка:

```
$('.user').css('display', 'none');
```

Я написал альтернативу на чистом JS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('user').style.display='none';
```

Но выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined

***Задача:* Присвоить всем элементам на странице с классом user свойство display: none**

**Ответ таков:**

```
var elems=document.getElementsByClassName('user');
for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++)elems[i].style.display='none';
```

Этот код ко всем элементам на странице с классом ***user*** присвоит ***display: none***

Comment: Так вы получаете массив элементов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ таков:

```
var elems=document.getElementsByClassName('user');
for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++)elems[i].style.display='none';
```

Этот код ко всем элементам на странице с классом ***user*** присвоит ***display: none***

Answer (score 3):

Так вы функцией `getElementsByClassName()` получаете массив (коллекцию) элементов, а у массива нет свойства `style`. О чем вам в ошибке и сказано.  Проходите циклом или применяйте к конкретному элементу.

Answer (score 1):

**getElementsByClassName** возвращает коллекцию/HTMLCollection (*не массив, как предположил @korytoff*) элементов , поэтому работать с ними надо либо по индексу, обращаясь к определенному, либо в цикле.

P.S. Кстати, рекомендую использовать не getElementsByClassName, а querySelector/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

Функция `getElementsByClassName()` вернет массив элементов. У массива нет свойства style, поэтому вылезает ошибка. Попробуйте так:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('user')[0].style.display='none';
```

если вам нужен только один элемент, либо же можно так:

```
var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('user'));
elements.forEach(function(e, i) {
    e.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Первая строчка создаст массив элементов, а следующей строкой начинается цикл обхода этих элементов и установление каждому из них `display: none`

Comment: Мне нужно убрать все элементы на странице с классом user (те. изменить display на none....)

А ваш код var elements... выдает ошибку:
Uncaught ReferenceError: querySelectorAll is not defined

Comment: Прошу прощения, `document.querySelectorAll()` конечно же. Поправил в ответе

Comment: Ничего, нашел такое решение:

`var elems=document.getElementsByClassName('user');
for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++)elems[i].style.display='none';`

Comment: Тоже правильное решение. Я его отметил, потому как более лаконичное