# Не работает модальное окно по примеру W3schools

Tags: javascript, jquery

Попробовала сделать модальное окно по [примеру](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp), но ничего не сработало. Буду благодарна тем, кто откроет мне глаза на ошибку в JS. Окно должно открываться по нажатии кнопки и закрываться по нажатию на Х.

P.S Написала более упрощенный вариант в плане стилей своего оригинального модального окна, но суть от этого не меняется.

```js
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("popup-inner");
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("popup-btn");
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close-button")[0];


btn.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

close.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.popup-inner {border: 1px solid black; height:200px; width:400px; background-color: pink;}
p {text-align: center; font-size: 36px;}
.close-button { position: relative; z-index: 100; float:right; margin-right:5px; margin-top: 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="popup-btn">click on me</button>
<div class="popup-inner">
<span class="close-button">X</span>
<p>My modal</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Почему все любят менять стили напрямую через js? Почему вы не хотите использовать вспомогательный класс для элемента, чтобы отталкиваясь от него менять стиль в самом css, а не напрямую через js. **.popup-inner.is-visible{display: block;}** К примеру.  Плюс запустите свой код и посмотрите на логи, вам выбивает ошибку, что объекта display попросту нет.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибку: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485703/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-display-of-undefined)

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName` возвращает коллекцию. Чтобы не было ошибки, и окно закрывалось, вот так нужно исправить первую строчку вашего js-кода:

```
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("popup-inner")[0];
```

Ещё можно это сделать через jQuery, ведь вы его уже подключаете.